# Having troubles with a matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I am struggling with a matrix problem from my textbook. These exercises are optional but I am preparing for a test coming in 10 days. Here is the problem:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be 2 x 2 matrices all of whose column sums are 1. Show that the column sums of $AB$ are 1.

Here is my progress so far, not very far but trying.
[image]

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Factor out the e in your first equation and use the fact that $a+c=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the right idea for the setup. I think you just need a little algebra to coax things out. For example $$ae+bg+ce+dg = e(a+c)+g(b+d)$$ You already know $a+c = b+d = e+g = 1$ so you can plug that into the RHS of the above equation to make your result fall out. $$e(a+c)+g(b+d) = e(1)+g(1) = e+g = 1$$ Just repeat the process with the right column of $AB$, or realize that you'd be doing the exact same process so the result follows.

Comment: Oh thanks, I guess I was overthinking it. But now I can see where I'm going. I appreciate it, my friend!

Comment: @SvenLion Happy to help!

Comment: I will after the 5 minutes pass. =)